# SQL Server 2008 with DPM 2010 & log shipping

Tags: sql-server-2008, scdpm

We are currently evaluating Data Protection Manger 2010 and need advice on the best SQL backup strategy for a 5GB database on SQL Server 2008.

Log shipping is setup on this so synchronization to DPM isn't possible, should more Express Full Backups be taken to compensate?

Also, we would like to have a monthly backup taken off site along with  each days transaction log backups.  How would this fit in with DPM or should agent jobs do this backup?

Answer (score 2):

Use the WITH COPY_ONLY option for any additional backups you wish to take off site.  The option does not interfere with any log shipping schedule or other scheduled backups.  Read the full store [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191495.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.  Would the following be advised: DPM takes 2 x Express full backups daily. Log shipping runs every 15 mins and these trn files are stored off site with a daily copy_only backup for recovery scenario where DPM isn't an option